# PHP MYSQL mysqli_fetch_array() no results (foreign characters)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bizarre one. I run mysqli_fetch_array all the time and I've never seen it give back no results before when I can echo out the SQL then insert it into PHPMYADMIN and get a result set back. Is it relevant that the results are in Japanese, is that what is causing the issue? Any help appreciated, code below:

```
$sqli_peekaboo = "SELECT KanjiElementKEB FROM stedict WHERE KanjiElementKEB =      '" . $line1word . "'";
echo $sqli_peekaboo . '<br>';
$result_sqli_peekaboo = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli_peekaboo);
while($row_peekaboo = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sqli_peekaboo))
{
echo '<br>Result:'.$row_peekaboo['KanjiElementKEB'].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the tips and suggestions. With your help I managed to fix it:
I changed the connection encryption, I've not done that before.

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "******", "******", "stedict") or mysqli_connect_error();
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: Yup - you need to set the enctype in the database itself, the database connector, ideally in the document header and the HTML ... just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the encoding before echoing the result, like this:

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Or, if it is a HTML page then in head tags give:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: An HTML 5 page should use `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Answer, I already had the charset at UTF-8. I replaced mine with yours incase I had a syntax error, still no result. It isn't echoing anything from the line echo '<br>Result:'.$row_peekaboo['KanjiElementKEB'].'<br>'; at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this, give it a try

```
 SELECT CONVERT(KanjiElementKEB USING utf8 )
 FROM stedict WHERE KanjiElementKEB =      '" . $line1word . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that play `$line1word` has something to do with it, as it is bound to be Japanese too. We don't see where `$line1word` is coming from, but assuming it's unfiltered, try this:

```
$sqli_peekaboo = "SELECT KanjiElementKEB FROM stedict WHERE KanjiElementKEB = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($line1word) . "'";
```

Also, may I ask why you are selecting only what you have already?

Comment: Hi, Thanks, in answer to why I'm selecting only what I have already, I simplified the requested result set for the question for ease of reading. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row_peekaboo = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sqli_peekaboo))
{
if(mb_detect_encoding($row_peekaboo['KanjiElementKEB'])=="UTF-8")
{
echo '<br>Result:'.utf8_decode($row_peekaboo['KanjiElementKEB']).'<br>';
 }
}
```